# Custom keyboard is crashing the app - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm doing a test of a custom keyboard. This is what I need:

1. It has to have two UITextFields. Cannot be labels.
2. The keyboard is an embedded UIView.
3. The default keyboard should be disabled.
4. It cannot be a keyboard extension.

Not sure why the app is crashing. PS: Not all the keys are on the code yet. Here is an image of what I'm trying to do and the two View Controllers.

Edit: The error is: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

First ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController, ButtonTapDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var keyboardView: UIView!

var buttonPressed = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    addKeyboard(view: keyboardView)
    buttonPressed = [String]()
    textField1.inputView = UIView()
    textField2.inputView = UIView()
}

func addKeyboard(view: UIView) {
    let keyboard = KeyboardVC(nibName: "KeyboardVC", bundle: nil)
    view.addSubview(keyboard.view)
    addChild(keyboard)
}

func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 5 {
        textField1.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")
    } else if sender.tag == 6 {
        textField1.text?.removeAll()
         buttonPressed = [String]()
    } else {
        let val = sender.titleLabel?.text
        textField1.text?.append(contentsOf: val!)
    }
    self.textField1.text = buttonPressed.joined(separator: "")
}
}
```

Here is the second View Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonTapDelegate {
    func didTapButton(sender: UIButton)
}

class KeyboardVC: UIViewController {

var delegate: ButtonTapDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.didTapButton(sender: sender)
    print(sender)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: `delegate` should be a regular optional, not an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var delegate: ButtonTapDelegate!
```

An implicitly unwrapped optional is essentially a promise that you're definitely going to give the variable a value before you try to access it.  The problem in this case is that you haven't done that. Most likely, you want to do this in your first view controller:

```
func addKeyboard(view: UIView) {
    let keyboard = KeyboardVC(nibName: "KeyboardVC", bundle: nil)
    keyboard.delegate = self // Now "delegate" will have a value before the function gets called
    view.addSubview(keyboard.view)
    addChild(keyboard)
}
```

Comment: This did it. Is not crashing anymore and is passing the info to the first view controller.